# How to remove items from contexts list

Tags: sharepoint-online

Been working on a new "intranet" for the company. We have MS365 and I have made a Sharepoint Communication site. Getting close to launch and want to know how I can remove options like Delete, Share, Rename, Move to, Automate from the three dot menu. It would be nice if I could remove people from seeing the three dots/context menu entirely. Really at a loss here at I thought I have made the write permission changes.

[image: Sharepoint three dot/context menu]

[image: Sharepoint permissions]

[image: Sharepoint group w/ permissions added]

Answer (score 0):

There is no OOB way to hide three dots in SharePoint library, restricted view permission could still see the option.

As a workaround, hide the Name column in document library, three dots disappear, then create a flow to copy the name value, then display it in another column:

[image]